# Does Linux Mint support PAE for 32-bit Cinnamon and MATE?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, pae, mate-desktop

Does Linux Mint 32-bit support PAE for both Cinnamon and MATE desktop environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, since Mint [is based on Ubuntu](http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php), it will support whatever the standard Ubuntu kernel supports.

Thus Mint 14 is based on Ubuntu 12.10's kernel, [which has PAE by default](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE).

Also, PAE has nothing to do with the desktop environment.

Comment: +1 for mentioning it is kernel-only issue.